# too many tcpv6/pipe open descriptors for kafka connections when using Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

We used Kafka Streams library for stream processing. But we have issues with too many tcpv6/pipe open descriptors which are used for connecting with kafka brokers.

The Kafka Stream code we use is similar like the code above, the differences are that we have more than 10 KStreams used for StreamsBuilder.

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-stream-processing-application");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(props);

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.<String, String>stream("my-input-topic").mapValues(value -> value.length().toString()).to("my-output-topic");

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
streams.start();
```

Will be really appreciated if anyone would give any help with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me, what your question is.

Comment: Hi Matthias, we have a kafka stream pipeline running which referenced the code above to start streams processing. But we got too many tcpv6/pipe open descriptors which related to kafka port 9092. We used "lsof" to list and see which and why there are so many open descriptors. And majority of them is about tcpv6 which port is 9092. Will be really appreciated if you can give any help :) @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: So I want to know what's the cause of too many tcpv6/pipe open descriptors which related to kafka port 9092.And how do we reduce the open descriptors. 
When I use netstat, it shows sth like this:
        tcp6       0      0 *kafka_broker_machine*:XmlIpcRegSvc *app machine*:35360 ESTABLISHED

Comment: Each Kafka Streams thread, uses 2 consumers and one producer and they all connect to the cluster. Thus it's expected that you have many open connections. I don't think there is lot you can do about it -- only, don't over provision your application with threads you don't need. We are working to reduce resource consumption in Kafka Streams for future releases already.

Comment: Correct me if my understanding was wrong. For example, we have 16 Kafka Streams, with 32 threads, then the total open descriptor would be 16*(2+1)*32?

Comment: And could you give me some advice about how many threads we need for my streaming process running in a single node. For my stream processor topology, I have 34 taskId based on 16 num of partitions. Then how many threads do we need to handle this?@MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: If you have 34 tasks, you don't need more than 34 thread -- all other thread will be idle anyway. You might even be able to run with fewer thread, depending on your throughput... But it's impossible to tell without monitoring the application, how many tasks a single thread can process -- you should monitor the lag and JMX metric to get some insights. (Your computation about connections sounds correct, if you run with 32 thread for each Kafka Streams instance).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Back to the original questions about "too many open descriptors", so for my streaming application, the number of open descriptors keeps growing dramatically every hour. Is that maybe because some kafka connections are not closed properly? @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: Not sure. Do you use interactive queries with Iterators? You must close() them, otherwise, you get a resource leak.